# как уменьшить "каретку" в PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти настройки этой части IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уменьшите значение `Line spacing`

File -> Settings -> Colors & Fonts -> Fonts -> Line spacing
(или откройте настройки и введите в поиске `Line spacing`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! все нормально теперь )